# Unable to connect to Visual Studio Local Host Webserver

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I got this error when I tried to run(F5) my project solution using  Visual Studio,then I did the following steps.......

I just did copy from other server which have visual studio installed then paste it in my local(c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727) webdev.webserver.exe  then I tried to run

**In Cmd Prompt:**

c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\WebDev.WebServer /?.

cd C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727--->aspnet_regiis -i
then iisrest

**Result:**
nothing is worked.Still I got Same Error...

**Error:**
How ever when I tried to run aspnet_regiis -i I got some error like

set up has detected some error and ask me to check log file ...from log file I got some failure status like:

C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\47223\aspnet_client
2012-06-29 12:58:20         Failure     Creating directory: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\47223\aspnet_client: CreateDirectoryInternal failed with HRESULT 80070003: 'The system cannot find the path specified.  '
2012-06-29 12:58:20     Failure     Creating list of client site scripts dirs: CreateSiteClientScriptDir failed with HRESULT 80070003: 'The system cannot find the path specified.  '

Could you please instruct me on this......

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After all above attemps I just repair my .Net Framework 2.0 and restart the system.Now its working so Good.Thanks